# Executing bash script in gradle

Tags: gradle, testing

I am doing functional testing with geb.

My application is deployed using virgo and uses HSQLDB to store data. I would like to perform tests on this working version of application, but I would like to start with empty database, every time I run webtests.

I wrote a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf $VIRGO_HOME/aresdb*
$VIRGO_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh &
sleep 10
$VIRGO_HOME/bin/startup.sh &
```

which removes the database and restarts virgo.

However, when I add it to my build.gradle task executing command never ends.

```
task cleanDB(type: Exec) {
    commandLine './clean.sh' 
}
```

Why is it this way? When I run this script in console it returns quickly (but virgo still writes to the console).

I have tried to run it in separate thread, but I encountered following error:

```
task cleanDBThread()<<{
    def cleanDBThread1 = Thread.start {
         cleanDB.execute()
    }
    sleep 10000
    println "wake up!"
}

Exception in thread "Thread-32" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Cannot start long running operation, as the task artifact state cache
(/home/tomasz/ares/.gradle/1.0-milestone-9/taskArtifacts) has not been locked.
```

I also tried setting 'create-drop' in hibernate configuration, but it also requires restarting virgo. Even redeploying the application does not help.

What should I do to run webtests with empty database?

Comment: What happens if you remove the & symbols from the end of your commands? I don't see a need for you to execute your commands in the background. Does this fix that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's weird

I created a task

```
task callCL(type: Exec) {
    commandLine './cl.sh'
}
```

that calls cl.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "starting "
./acl.sh &
sleep 10
./acl.sh &
```

that call acl.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "I am not doing anything"
```

and it worked! but one thing though, when you add ./acl.sh ampersand character ***&*** you're calling the task from a different thread that started gradle, and kinda looks like it's hanging. I would remove the & from your calls to shutdown and start like this

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf $VIRGO_HOME/aresdb*
$VIRGO_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
$VIRGO_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

anyways you want to wait in the same thread from shutdown to start, and no need to call sleep too!

Comment: This has been deprecated in later versions. I'm using gradle 7.4.2 and I get an error.

Comment: @CaptainChaos New version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74423801/1161484)

Comment: Is it working on windows?

Answer (score 3):

As [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804023/executing-bash-script-in-gradle#comment129080569_10883887) by @captain-chaos notes, `commandLine` has been deprecated.

The following is the new syntax which should work:

```
task callCL(type: Exec) {
    executable "sh"
    args "-c", "./cl.sh"
}
```