# Execute shell script in android gradle

Tags: android, bash, jenkins, build, android-gradle-plugin

I want to run a shell script to change the value in string.xml when my app is built. Where should I run my script in gradle, since there is no task in it. Or, because I will build the app use Jenkins, should I run the script on Jenkins server? Please help me out.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 22
     buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
     }

defaultConfig {
   .......
     }

buildTypes {
    release {
      .......
       }
     }

productFlavors {
    development {}
    production {}
     }

sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        setRoot('src/test')
              }
     }

packagingOptions {..}


dependencies {...}
```

Comment: Same problem here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804023/executing-bash-script-in-gradle

Sincerly yours.

Comment: I have seen that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `preBuild` step that runs the script and makes it depend on build.

```
task myPreBuild << {
   commandLine './script.sh'
}
build.dependsOn myPreBuild
```

Comment: thanks. BTY, where should I put my script? In res/raw/ or somewhere else?

Comment: Im not too sure. I usually put mine in a scripts folder.

Comment: I use preBuild.dependsOn command, it can recognize. But the build failed, maybe some problem with my path? I put the script on my local "commandLine 'sh /home/czhu/lokki/editxml.sh' ".

Comment: Your probably need to prepend with 'sh', e.g. 'sh ./script.sh'